# Question on finding eigenvalues of another linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a quick question on finding eigenvectors for a linear transformation. I'm given:

$T(A) = A^t$ where $A = M_2$ i.e. a $2 \times 2$ matrix consisting of real numbers.

So the general approach is to solve $T(v) = \lambda v$, and from there I set up:

$$
\left\{\begin{align*}
a &= \lambda a \\
d &= \lambda d \\
b &= \lambda c \\
c &= \lambda b
\end{align*}\right. $$

which suggests that that $\lambda = 1$ is the only eigenvalue. Given that, I can verify that $T(v) = \lambda v$ holds when $\lambda = 1$ and $b = c$.

But I'm not sure how to describe the eigenvector. How do I put it into terms? I was thinking that a basis for the solution set would be:

$$a  \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0  \end{pmatrix} 
+ d  \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1  \end{pmatrix} 
+ 
b\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\\
1 & 0  \end{pmatrix} $$

but that's not an eigenvector. How exactly would I describe the eigenvector for $\lambda = 1$?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: So if you have a matrix with two eigenvectors, both of which are 2 x 2 matrices, how would you go about diagonalizing it? i.e. if you have to solve $\Lambda = SAS^{-1}$, how do you determine S?

Comment: Why do you say that the matrix you've written is not an eigenvector? The eigenvectors for the eigenvalue $1$ are the symmetric matrices.

Comment: Oh okay, I didn't realize that. So is 1 the only eigenvalue as well, or are there other solutions? Also, let's say if we later wanted to diagonalize A, but had an "eigenelement," how would we derive S? Normally I just put the eigenvectors in, but if the eigenvectors were 2x2 matrices, would S have blocks of eigenvectors?

Comment: $-1$ is also an eigenvalue, with eigenvector the skew-symmetric matrices.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Is there a systematic way to find eigenvalues once you have your equations, or is it mostly check specific values and see what happens?

Comment: The lats two equations give that $b(\lambda^2-1)=0$, so either you choose $b=0$, then $a$ or $d$ is not $0$ and $\lambda =1$, or you choose $b\neq 0$, so $\lambda=\pm 1$. Either you take $a=d=0$ (so $\lambda=-1$) or you pick $a$ or $d\neq 0$ and $\lambda=1$.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that generally, for small dimensional vector spaces like this one, it is more difficult to try to solve the equation $T(\mathbf{v})=\lambda\mathbf{v}$ *simultaneously* for $\lambda$ and for nonzero $\mathbf{v}$, than to simply go ahead, find a basis for $\mathbf{V}$, determine the matrix of $T$ relative to the basis, and *then* use the characteristic polynomial of the matrix to find the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're confused by the two different uses of the term "vector". In one use, a vector is a column or row of numbers, a matrix one of whose dimensions is $1$. In another use, a vector is any element of any [vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space). It is this second sense of the term that's being used when we say that the matrices you describe in your last displayed equation are the eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$ of this linear transformation.

The equation $\Lambda = SAS^{-1}$ doesn't make sense here since you're examining the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $T$, not of $A$, so you want $\Lambda = STS^{-1}$. You can choose a basis for the vector space of $2\times2$ matrices, for instance the canonical basis, and then express $T$ as a $4\times4$ matrix with respect to this basis. If you also express the eigenvectors you found (three for $1$ and one for $-1$) in this basis, you'll find that they are eigenvectors, in the first sense of the word, of the $4\times4$ matrix representing $T$, and that a $4\times4$ matrix formed out of them diagonalizes the matrix representing $T$.

Comment: I didn't realize that a eigenvector can be bigger than $n x 1$. I did edit my question in the end though, so if you could take a look at that, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Arturo and joriki gave you good advices. You should find the matrix of your endomorphism $T(A) = A^t$ associated to the standard basis of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$:

$$
E_1 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1    &   0  \\
0    &   0
\end{pmatrix}
\ , \qquad 
E_2 =
\begin{pmatrix}
0    &   1  \\
0    &   0
\end{pmatrix}
\ , \qquad 
E_3 =
\begin{pmatrix}
0    &   0  \\
1    &   0
\end{pmatrix}
\ , \qquad 
E_4 =
\begin{pmatrix}
0    &   0  \\
0    &   1
\end{pmatrix}
\ . 
$$

That is,

$$
T(E_1) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1    &   0  \\
0    &   0
\end{pmatrix}
\ , \qquad 
T(E_2) =
\begin{pmatrix}
0    &   0  \\
1    &   0
\end{pmatrix}
\ , \qquad 
T(E_3) =
\begin{pmatrix}
0    &   1  \\
0    &   0
\end{pmatrix}
\ , \qquad 
T(E_4) =
\begin{pmatrix}
0    &   0  \\
0    &   1
\end{pmatrix}
\ . 
$$

From which you immediatly realise that there is at least one eigenvalue, $1$, with at least a $2$-dimensional subspace of eigenvectors -the span of $E_1$ and $E_4$. To get everything, you just put this data into the associated matrix of $T$:

$$
M =
\begin{pmatrix}
1  &  0  &  0  &  0  \\
0  &  0  &  1  &  0  \\
0  &  1  &  0  &  0  \\
0  &  0  &  0  &  1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

compute its characteristic polynomial:

$$
Q_M(t) = (t-1)^3 (t+1)
$$

and find out that there was an eigenvalue you didn't see: $-1$.

If you compute now the respective eigenspaces, you'll find that

$$
\ker (M - I ) = \mathrm{span} (E_1, E_2 + E_3, E_4)
$$

is the subspace of symmetric matrices and

$$
\ker (M + I) = \mathrm{span}(E_2 - E_3)
$$

is the subspace of skew-symmetric matrices.